# Set-DFSnRoot not setting the referral path of map drive

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I have one map drive created in windows server, which is using DFS path
`\\platdc.local\DFSPLAT2\DBBSETUP2-Plat`.
I want to check which refferal path is currently active in the DFS property of Map drive.

[image]

And if PlatDC-PrimaryFileServer is not active then active it using powershell script.

I tried differnt powershell code but did not work.

```
$referralPath = "\\Plat2-Secondary\DBBSETUP2-Plat"

$referralPriority = 1

$timeToLive = 300

$dfsFolderTarget = Get-DfsnFolderTarget -Path "\\platdc.local\DFSPLAT2\DBBSETUP2-Plat"

$referral = @{
    Path = $referralPath
    ReferralPriority = $referralPriority
}

$dfsFolderTarget.ReferralPriority = $referral

Set-DfsnFolderTarget -InputObject $dfsFolderTarget -TimeToLive $timeToLive
```

Comment: What are the "different powershell code" have you tried so far? Kindly post your set of codes and explain where exactly you are struggling.

Comment: yes I've added the code block.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt work on the paths as I am confused on your path variables. So, I am simplifying the logic for you. The State method clearly tells you if the drive is Online or not. Based on that, you can form a logic to check and take action accordingly. Below is the simplified version of what you were trying to achieve.

```
$referralPath = "\\Plat2-Secondary\DBBSETUP2-Plat" #Being the Path

$targetpath = "\\platdc.local\DFSPLAT2\DBBSETUP2-Plat" #Being the Targetpath


if(!((Get-DfsnFolderTarget -Path $referralPath -TargetPath $targetpath).State -eq 'Online')) # Checking if the Target is not online
    {
        Set-DfsnFolderTarget -Path $referralPath -TargetPath $targetpath -State Online
    }
else
    {
        "$targetpath is already Online"
    }
```

For further parameters, please refer [Set-DfsnFolderTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dfsn/set-dfsnfoldertarget?view=windowsserver2022-ps) and [Get-DfsnFolderTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dfsn/get-dfsnfoldertarget?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Comment: I think the target path and referral path is the same
$referralPath = "\\Plat2-Secondary\DBBSETUP2-Plat" 
$path = "\\platdc.local\DFSPLAT2\DBBSETUP2-Plat" is my full UNC path. 
And in my case state is already "Online" I wanted the command that just activate the referral path.

Comment: @ShritejMurmadkar: I have already given the command to activate it. Making the state Online is to confirm that its active. But I cannot confirm your path. That's something you need to check on your own. Good Luck